# Error: Cannot find module 'sendgrid' when using sendgrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, sendgrid

I keep getting an 'Error: Cannot find module 'sendgrid' in my console when attempting to execute my code. I have never used sendgrid before, am I doing something wrong?

```
 SENDGRID =
  "<key>";

const sgMail = require("sendgrid").SendGrid(conf);
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID);

const msg = {
  to: "eden.cmo@gmail.com", // Change to your recipient
  from: "test.test@gmail.com", // Change to your verified sender
  subject: "Sending with SendGrid is Fun",
  text: "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",
  html: "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>",
};

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Email sent");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

Error: Cannot find module 'sendgrid'
Require stack:
- /Users/tategraham/Downloads/send grid/sendGrid.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:900:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:745:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tategraham/Downloads/send grid/sendGrid.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/tategraham/Downloads/send grid/sendGrid.js' ]
}
tategraham@MacBook-Pro send grid %
```

Comment: 1. Don't post sensitive content (revoke that key immediately). 2. The package is `@sendgrid/client
`

Comment: Did you install the module? Also [sendgrid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid) is deprecated, new package can be found at [@sendgrid/mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail)

Comment: I am now getting this error: ategraham@MacBook-Pro send grid % node sendGrid.js
API key does not start with "SG.".
ResponseError: Unauthorized
    at node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:145:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
```

**Here is a link to actual doc:**
https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-nodejs/#complete-code-block

**Update On Using The Environment Variable**

First create .env file something like sendgrid.env. Then you can use `require('dotenv').config(sendgrid.env)`
or maybe, just
`require('dotenv').config(sendgrid)`

Then you can use SENDGRID_API_KEY defined in that env file At least this can be done according to my understanding to your question.

Comment: Thanks - How to I create an environment variable?

Comment: @TateGraham have a look at [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). It is used for creating and reading environment variables from a `.env` file